# Still players keep moving on the clients

Tags: unity, interpolation, unet

With UNET, despite `Interpolation` is set to `None` in the `NetworkTransform`, I've noticed that still players keep moving on the clients, very slowly, one pixel at a time.

Their position on the server is correct, and as soon as they move again, they warp to where they should actually be and go on. As soon as they stop, the slow horizontal movement often starts again.

This happens most often with *yourself*, and only sometimes to others. Sometimes you see yourself moving, while others will see you correctly, while some other times you also see others moving.

Googling around yielded no results, and other than disabling interpolation, which I already tried, I'm a bit clueless about what to do.

What could be causing this, and how could I fix it?